# Selecting duplicate IDs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, select-by-expression

I have a .csv file in QGIS with a list of water meters and their associated property IDs. Some property IDs have >1 water meter. I want to run a selection query to find all the duplicate property IDs.

My expression attempt so far is as follows:

```
IF(COUNT( "Property ID" , "Property ID" )>1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

This creates a selection but it doesn't grab all the records. It grabs the duplicates but not the first duplicate.

In my head, it's working like this:

1. Finds property ID 1234
2. Looks through the list for all matching IDs 1234
3. Finds 1234 3 times (4 in total including original)
4. Then adds the 3 matching IDs to a selection but leaves out the first 1234 ID

With this selection I want to compare them to my property layer and see that each property has the correct number of water meters. I tried using ChatGPT to help but no dice. I also used the suggestion that pop up when entering in the title to a question but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2):

After selecting all features, use the following expression with "*Remove from Current Selection*" option.

```
array_first( 
    array_agg(
        $id,
        "Property ID",
        order_by:=$id 
    )
) = $id
```

[image]